# Rails - Checking whether an associated object is destroyed, with model callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

I'm trying to catch if an associated object is destroyed when the parent object is updated. So far I tried below approach but it doesn't work.

```rb
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_sets, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_sets, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  after_save :check_changes

  private

  def check_changes
    tag_sets.any? { |t| t.changed? || t.destoyed? }
  end
end
```

I can catch any change on associated objects but not the destroyed ones. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What code are you running to destroy the dependent objects on update? They're typically only destroyed when the parent is.

Comment: Actually I'm using cacoon gem for the nested attributes. I'm not doing anything specifically for destroying the object. It's being done in TagsController#update action